# How do you pass HTML variables to google app scripts

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I'm writing some to get the user's input in a text area and then to pass it to google app scripts to my main google script to email it on. I also tried to pass them through the project properties with no luck.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
  <p style="font-family:verdana;font-size:15px">Problem title</p>
  <input type="text" id="sDes"> <br><br>
  <p style="font-family:verdana;font-size:15px">Decription</p>
  <textarea style="resize: none;" rows="8" cols="63" id="lDes"></textarea>
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Send</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var a = document.getElementById("sDes").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("lDes").value;
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, from your question, I'm not sure about your issue. When your HTML is included in the Google Apps Script project, you can achieve your goal using [`google.script.run`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run). When your HTML is not included in the GAS project, for example, when it is put to your local PC, you can achieve your goal using [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web). About these cases, I think that you can see the sample scripts in Stackoverflow. If this was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. run the openDialog() function after filling in serverfunctionname and htmlfilename.

Your html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
  <p style="font-family:verdana;font-size:15px">Problem title</p>
  <input type="text" id="sDes"> <br><br>
  <p style="font-family:verdana;font-size:15px">Decription</p>
  <textarea style="resize: none;" rows="8" cols="63" id="lDes"></textarea>
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Send</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var a = document.getElementById("sDes").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("lDes").value;
    google.script.run.serverfunctionname(a,b);//modification
  }
</script>

</html>
```

GS:

```
function serverfunctioname(x,y) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('I received ' + x + ' and ' + y);
}


function openDialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('htmlfilename'), "My Dialog")
}
```